# SQLite ... pass two parameters (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to pass two parameters to a createStatement as follow :

```
_isKnownResultURL: function(url, engine)
{
    var st = this.dbh.createStatement("select 1 from ext_Google where _url = ?1 and _engine = ?2;");
    st.bindUTF8StringParameter(0, url);
    st.bindUTF8StringParameter(1, engine);

    if(st.executeStep())
    {
        st.reset();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

but it gives me an error

```
Horodatage : 03/07/2013 12:39:41
Erreur : NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

when i pass just one it works but with two i get the mention error.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ensured that url and engine are strings?

Comment: perhaps the ; inside the quotes is throwing it off?

Comment: It is working now, the problem was in the table not the code. ^^'